# Thumbnail (featured image) and Media Library cleanup queries help needed

Tags: post-thumbnails, media-library

I inherited a website that was started 13 years ago, over the years the version of WP and themes have been kept current, however much of the older content (and there is a ton of it) was created long before the concept of the 'featured image' (thumbnail) so it uses a custom field in which the image filename is stored as post metadata and also the alt-text for the image is stored in another custom field.

With each Theme update I've had to modify the (child theme) templates to find and use the metadata instead of simply making use of the more simple thumbnail functions, but I'm at a point now where I'd really like to convert all those old images from the custom field to a thumbnail to simplify future Theme updates.

I'm very good at modifying code I find elsewhere and am good at using phpMyAdmin to tweak my database, but I do not know how to write the necessary PHP query to find all those images in my database and associate them with the right table so that they can appear as the featured image. Ideally converting the alt-text too would be nice to preserve both the accessibility and the SEO benefit, but not as critical as I can work around that.

One problem is that most of those images are NOT in the Media Library already as they were not added using that (media upload) function, they were just uploaded via FTP.

Is there a way to use a PHP query in phpMyAdmin to accomplish this? Move the images to the Media Library and assign them to their current post as the featured/thumbnail image?

The second part of this process, assuming I can get thru the first part, is to then clean out all images that are not "attached" to Posts.  Since currently they're a custom field and not 'attached', I can't clean up the /images folder or Media Library, but there are literally thousands of images that are not in use, one of the early users just uploaded tons of stock images from CDs with the idea that they *might* use them someday, again mostly via FTP and so they're not in the Media Library, but I'd really like to clean it all up.

I'm open to ALL suggestions!  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: There are probably a few ways to get you part of the way, but what have you tried to do this? Also, is there a reason, besides cleanliness, to remove the images on the server? Are you running out of space? Since the images are not in the media library and WordPress isn't actively using them, the only thing this would essentially fix would be server space - if you need it. If you know the custom meta key that the images are currently attached to, you could export a list of those images to know what ones are in use, but you'd most likely have to manually clean up your directory.

Comment: Thanks - good questions. Not running out of space, it's truly mostly for cleanliness.  I haven't dared to try much because I don't know enough to attempt a PHP query without help. I do like your suggestion of exporting a list to try to identify which images are in uset, but I still need to bulk-migrate the ones in use to 'thumbnail', doing that manually would take months and I just want to get it in good shape for someone else to take over without needing the template workaround (which has also required Theme Widget mods too where they use 'thumbnail' and so don't show images).